# Remove/Strip out "<" tags from a textbox value in jquery

Tags: jquery, regex, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a form wherein I prevent users from entering tags ('<' & '>') using regex. But the problem is that if the user enters say test with "<" tag then to it accepts the input and throws a potential dangerous request. So I want to try and strip out "<" tag from value I get from the textbox.
Following is my form post line:

```
<div>
        @Using Html.BeginForm("Add", "New", FormMethod.Post, New With {.id = "newForm", .class = "validation"})
            @Html.Partial("Shared/_Update", Model)
        End Using
    </div>
```

I tried using the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var form = $('#newForm');
    form.submit(function () {            
        var name = $("#tbo_Name").val();
        name = name.replace("/\</g", "");            
        $("#tbo_Name").attr("value", name));
    })
});<script>
```

But the above does not strip out "<" tags in jquery. Which other methods or code I can use.

Also the other thing I thought about is what if I pass form values as HTML below my form post method, just how we pass HTML.hidden values.

So want a help on the same on how to strip out tag "<". Any suggestions or help on the same?.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: It's better to `encode` the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the quotes which exists around the regex delimiters `/regex/`

```
name = name.replace(/</g, "");
```